# error MIDL2079 no [uuid] specified : [Library "LibraryName"]

Tags: visual-c++, idl

I'm a newbie at programming idl extensions. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 and I get this compile error. I hope that somebody could help me.

```
library LibraryName{
 importlib("Stdole32.tlb");
[uuid(756da9cb-3201-4ed8-9680-920fc16017ff), version(1.0)]
coclass Name
{[default] interface IName1;
interface Name2;}};
```

Comment: Yes, a library always needs a [uuid]. It sets the TLBID, very important because programmers tend to suck at picking unique names. Like "LibraryName", somebody thought of that one before and you never want to meet on a machine that neither of you know about. You know what it looks like, a coclass need to be unique as well, consider using it.  Don't forget [version] either, very, **very**, important, libraries need versions.

Comment: That's the part of the Library and I used an unique uuid and also I added the version. But I have the same error compiler. error MIDL2079:no uuid specified : [Library 'LibraryName']. I don't know what I should do. Please I need help with it.

Comment: I can't guess what you still are doing wrong when you don't update your question with your changes.  At least [look at an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690150(v=vs.85).aspx) of what it needs to look like, example2.idl

Comment: You put the [version] attribute on the coclass, not the library.  They must be written **before** the library keyword.  Just as the attributes for the coclass were written before the coclass keyword.  Well demonstrated in the example2.idl I linked to.  Right now your library has no attributes at all, that is what MIDL is complaining about.

Comment: what I do wrong? My interface part is: `[object, uuid(0d000781-3204-d321-8723-9832-13427831), version(1.0), dual, ]pointer_default(unique)] interface IName2:Unknown{HRESULT ServerClient ([in] long Max)};`The library part is like above.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  @hans